# Dataflow doesn't update GroupByKey's "Output collections" field

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, apache-beam

[image: As can be seen here] Dataflow does not update `GroupByKey`'s `Output Collections` even though I can see the output data in cloud storage (the next transform in the pipeline writes the output to GCS). None of the transforms after `GroupByKey` show input/output collections either. I have also tried to implement data-driven triggering using `AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(3000)` but then too the `Output Collections` does not get updated after `3000` elements have been input.

The problem is that the `Estimated Size` keeps on increasing and I am afraid that it will eventually lead to more workers costing me more money. I have been waiting for more than an hour but it still doesn't get updated. I have an unbounded PCollection and I have set the windowing and triggering as shown below

```
input
  .apply(
    Window
      .into[String](FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(windowSize)))
      .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(windowSize))
      .discardingFiredPanes()
      .triggering(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(3000)))
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: Google has optimize shuffle based operation https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#shuffle-optimization Try to use --experiments=shuffle_mode=service

Comment: The Estimated Size/Elements Added counters are not used for billing. As such, they are a 'best effort' counter, and are only approximate. Dataflow does not use them when determining workers/billing/execution.

Comment: @pablo I see. Do you know why it might not be updating the output collections though?

Comment: Can you share a Job ID? Could you share more about what your pipeline does after the GroupByKey?

Comment: @BenChambers There is just one transform after `GroupByKey` that writes each element (k-v pair) to a separate file on GCS. It shows `Elements added -` and `Estimated size -` under `Input Collections` but the output files do exist in my GCS bucket.

Comment: Job ID? What version of the SDK?

Comment: @BenChambers I cannot share the Job ID. I am using Apache Beam 2.0.0.

Comment: Kakaji - unfortunately we (the Dataflow team) likely won't be able to debug your job without knowing the job ID. Please note that the job ID does not contain any sensitive/confidential data - it's a string of the form "2017-07-07_02_35_01-2026862183898875063" (I took an example job ID from one of our projects), so basically a date/time and a random number, which is safe to post on a public forum. Not to be confused with "job name" which may be a bit more sensitive.

Comment: @BenChambers 2017-07-24_03_12_08-12234191318281269878 Here you go.